Extract query string from url
Looking for an approach to extract the query string from the URL such that a scenario where the query string is empty or not present is also addressed. I have following but would be helpful if there is a better approach.
let qryStr = "b="; // 'b' is the query-stirng. Need to extract its value
let T = datatable(url: string)
    [
    "https://example.com/abc.htm?a=1&b=2&c=3",
    "https://example.org/abc.htm?a=1&c=3&b=2",
    "https://example.net/abc.htm?b=2&a=1&c=3",
    "https://example.net/abc.htm?a=1&c=3",
    "https://example.net/abc.htm?a=1&c=3&b="
];
T
| project url
| extend s1 = indexof(url, qryStr)
| where s1 > 0
| extend value=split(substring(url, s1 + strlen(qryStr)), "&")[0]
| project url, ['qryStr'], value, s1


You can try with parse_url().
let qryStr = "b"; // 'b' is the query-stirng. Need to extract its value
let T = datatable(url: string)
    [
    "https://example.com/abc.htm?a=1&b=2&c=3",
    "https://example.org/abc.htm?a=1&c=3&b=2",
    "https://example.net/abc.htm?b=2&a=1&c=3",
    "https://example.net/abc.htm?a=1&c=3",
    "https://example.net/abc.htm?a=1&c=3&b="
];
T
| project url
| extend value = parse_url(url)["Query Parameters"][qryStr]
| project url, ['qryStr'], value


where s1 > 0 removes the record itself whose URL does not have query string. Instead you can use iif conditional expression and assign empty string value for all URLs who didn't have query string. Below is the code.
let qryStr = "b="; // 'b' is the query-stirng. Need to extract its value
let T = datatable(url: string)
    [
    "https://example.com/abc.htm?a=1&b=2&c=3",
    "https://example.org/abc.htm?a=1&c=3&b=2",
    "https://example.net/abc.htm?b=2&a=1&c=3",
    "https://example.net/abc.htm?a=1&c=3",
    "https://example.net/abc.htm?a=1&c=3&b="
];
T
| project url
| extend s1 = indexof(url, qryStr)
| extend value=iif(s1>0,split(substring(url, s1 + strlen(qryStr)), "&")[0],'')
| project url, ['qryStr'], value, s1

demo
